# How to set an attribute as an array of objects or a pointer in visio 2007?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, uml, visio

How to set an attribute as an array of objects or a pointer in visio 2007 (I assume it's the same in 2010 if you only know 2010)? As an example, one of my class has a bookOut attribute which is an array of Books so I'd like Book[]. I'd also need a Book* for something else.

Comment: Sorry I'm missing something.. how is this C++ related??

Comment: in the list of Visio tutorials that Google returns there is also [Creating UML Class Diagrams with Visio](http://youtu.be/Ksnb8VAuJ48). BTW: Visio is not really an UML modeling tool. If you use it just because you have a license and you have trouble using it then perhaps try some alternative ([some tips](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26058548/2626313))