# Dia Sequence Diagram Loop

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, dia

How would you represent a loop in a Dia Sequence Diagram.  Ideally I would like to be able to make edits to the items inside the loop areas so a standard box or large package don't seem to allow edits underneath.  Any ideas?

Comment: Slightly similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038670/dia-the-diagram-editor-limits-on-box-objects

Comment: I would imagine that there is some way to do this without customizing settings.

Comment: Maybe, my point was that Dia is not real UML modeling tool, it is just a vector image drawing tool and that you might consider using some real UML modeling tool where such things are often more straightforward. I'm not Dia user so I won't help you any further

Answer (score 1):

There is no official UML way to do it in dia. You can look at all the templates for something that is similare, but using a transparant box is the best option at this moment. Dia is great for class diagrams and use-case diagrams, but for Sequence Diagrams, there are alot of great (free) alternatives.

The most simple solution for you problem is to use Layers. On the top layer, you place the 'loop' and on the bottom layer you edit your diagram.

**Menu > Layers > "Add layer"**